# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataBind'

Tags: knockout.js

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataBind' 
Geting this error needs to segregate data binding from presentation (HTML)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

Choose a ticket class:
    <select id='tickets'></select>
<p id='ticketOutput'></p>
<script id="ticketTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if chosenTicket}}
        You have chosen <b>${ chosenTicket().name }</b>
    ($${ chosenTicket().price })
        <button data-bind="click: resetTicket">Clear</button>
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        tickets: [
            { name: "Economy", price: 199.95 },
            { name: "Business", price: 449.22 },
            { name: "First Class", price: 1199.99 }
        ],
        chosenTicket: ko.observable(),
        resetTicket: function () { this.chosenTicket(null) }
    };
    $('#tickets').dataBind({
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataBind'
        options: 'tickets',
        optionsCaption: "'Choose...'",
        optionsText: "'name'",
        value: 'chosenTicket'
    });
    $('#ticketOutput').dataBind({ template: "'ticketTemplate'" });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Great. Show some code, please.

Comment: Show some code and not just the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataBind function is part of the unobtrusive Knockout library, and it doesn't come by default with jQuery.

You need to add the reference to your page to be able to use it. That's why you're getting the 'has no method dataBind' error.

[Unobtrusive Knockout]
http://userinexperience.com/?p=689

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a jQuery plugin you're not showing in the sample, there is no jQuery dataBind function

Apply the databind to the html element itself instead. Change

```
<p id='ticketOutput'></p>
```

to

```
<p id='ticketOutput' data-bind=" template: 'ticketTemplate' "></p>
```

and remove that $.dataBind call right before apply bindings

Do the same for the "#tickets" databind as well

EDIT: Actually there were tons of problems with this question, so I made a jsfiddle showing the correct way to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/TAVgp/

Comment: Thanks its really helpful, but want to segregate data binding from presentation. JsFiddle helps alot thanks again :), Missed to include - knockout.unobtrusive.js